# Issue with download a file from FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp

Whenever I try to download file from this ftp server, i get this error:

`System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode (37,60,247,183,135,216)`

```
public static main(string[] args){

    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.autoherosrpg.com/hash.xml");
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("game@autoherosrpg.com", "*********");
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse();
}
```

but even if I switch 'UsePassive' to false, I get:

```
public static main(string[] args){

    FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
    FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
    ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.autoherosrpg.com/hash.xml");
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("game@autoherosrpg.com", "*********");
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse) ftpRequest.GetResponse();
}
```

`System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized.'`

This is the first time I am trying to connect to a ftp server via C#. This connection works in any ftp client and in the browser

Update:
The FTP server does not support TLS as right now. Once I get this code working with a server without encryption, I will modify the code to use TLS.

[FTP Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qyiyvpbmqypsy75/ftp.autoherosrpg.com-ftp_log-Jan-2018?dl=0)

Comment: Can you connect to the FTP server using any standalone FTP client from the same machine that you run your C# code at? Show us its log file.

Comment: Yes i can. I stated that at the end of my post that if i tired any ftp client or the browser, i can connect to the ftp server. I can post the log file

Comment: That's a useless log. It does not show FTP protocol transcript. Is it server-side log? Show us **verbose** client-side log.

Answer (score -1):

When you switch to "UsePassive" as you said, it return "Syntax error, command unrecognized". That's mean you wrong syntax somewhere, cause you don't public full source code here so I can't figure out exactly.

Comment: That is the only code that I added to the static main method within the Program class, that is create when create a console project within visual studio. I did not make public the username, and password for security reason, but they are string. i have update the code above to reflect that.